# Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2)

Tags: android-studio

I got this error from my android studio 3.2 when am trying to build my project. Am new to android and i have been trying to set the studio up but i keep getting this error - `Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2): No cached version available for offline mode`
someone should help me out and fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not finished setting up your Android studio. Make sure you are connected to the internet then press **Try Again** or **Restart** your android or **Press the sync again** button on the top left corner of android studio. Gradle will be downloaded

It is important to make sure that your android studio is not in offline mode. To do this go o **File**->**Settings** the search Offline in the settings search box. Choose gradle and make sure the Offline check box is not Checked.

Comment: unchecking the offline mode work for me thanks! Martin Mbae